# Word document not showing all of its content

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I'm finding it difficult to search for this problem as I'm not sure exactly what's happening.

Some parts of my document seem to be hidden, including any images. The pages look smaller than their size (A4) but when looking at print preview, everything appears normal size with all the whitespace i'd expect. I can't see any hidden text and have tried various view settings. The only thing I can relate this to is hidden cells in Excel, it seems to be quite similar behavior.

Images to show what is happening below. Note the line prior to the contents page where the section break appears. That's where the first page ends but in the preview, it's a full size A4 page?!

(Content obfuscated due to confidentiality)

[image: Document view]
[image: Print preview]

Comment: Double click the line between the pages. It's a display options to hide whitespaces.

Comment: Ha! That was easy - thanks. Feel free to post as an answer. I can't believe I didn't even think to try that

Answer (score 0):

Double click line between pages.